# how to do formatting of cell in excelLibrary

Tags: asp.net, excel

I want to create excel file in ASP.net I used  ExcelLibraby, It works fine if there is no any date column. But If there is date then it convert to like 42005
for date 2015-01-01. How do I formatting on cell then I get correct formatted date in excel sheet.

I used only one line code to create excel sheet as follow

```
ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook(@"C:\Users\ABC\Documents\Excel\Report.xls", ds);
```

Comment: Put some code/link in support of your question. What you have tried so far.

Comment: Use a [Range.NumberFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx) of *yyyy-mm-dd*.

Comment: @shekhar- See Updated question , I used only one line of code

Comment: @Jeeped- Can u please help me use this proprty , If I used only one line of code to create excel